# Auto Complete source response

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the first time I come on this platform.

I need a little help I try to modify this code to integrate my data but I can't do it.

Here is my Return json and my JS

Json

```
{"data":[{"id":6,"name":"City1","lat":"56.401488","lon":"6.590949"},{"id":7,"name":"City2","lat":"56.373565","lon":"6.477635"}]}
```

Js

```
        if( $("input.search_location_js").length > 0 ) {
        jQuery('input.search_location_js').autocomplete( {
                             
            source: function ( request, response ) {
                    jQuery.get( 'https://URL.com/data/public/items/city', {
                            q: request.term,
                            limit:'4',
                    }, function( result ) {
                       
                            if ( !result.length ) {
                                response( [ {
                                    value: 'nc',
                                    latitude:'56.3667',
                                    longitude:'56.4833',
                                    label: 'nc'
                                }]                                          
                                );
                                return;
                            }
                            
                            response( result.map( function ( place ) {
                        
                                    return {
                                            label: place.data[*][*].nom,
                                            latitude: place.data[*][*].lat,
                                            longitude: place.data[*][*].lon,
                                            value: place.data[*][*].nom,
                                    };
                            } ) );
                    }, 'json' );
            },
            select: function ( event, ui ) {
                
                $('input[name="lat"]').val(ui.item.latitude);
                $('input[name="lng"]').val(ui.item.longitude);

                if(is_halfmap) {
                    var current_page = 0;
                    dps_search_on_change(current_page);
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

place.data[*][*].name I want to retrieve the name of the cities in the json but the above path doesn't work

I also tested
.data.name and
.data[i].name ...

ps : my problem is in this portion of the code

```
response( result.map( function ( place ) {
                    
                                return {
                                        label: place.data[*][*].nom,
                                        latitude: place.data[*][*].lat,
                                        longitude: place.data[*][*].lon,
                                        value: place.data[*][*].nom,
                                };
                        } )
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Did you try result.data.map(function(place) {  .... place.name ... }) ?

Comment: domenikk : I've just tried it but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I'm still looking and I can't find it. I think it's link to object and array I can't find any solution that works.